# Control values lost when authentication session times out in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, postback

I have a ASP.NET website which uses forms authentication. The timeout is twenty minutes.

I have noticed that if a user half completes a form, and is then timed out, they are redirected to the login page, fill it in, and are redirected back to the form but with EMPTY controls.

I had prevously assumed that ASP.NET would use some skulduggery to repopulate the form controls when this happens.

Are there changes I can make to make sure it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to your problem is to set the [`slidingExpiration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx) attribute to `true` on the forms authentication element in web.config. This way the user only loses his/her data when they take in excess of 20 minutes to fill in the form.

The problem occurs because asp.net "remembers" values that have been entered in the form by means of a concept called viewstate, which is basically just a hidden form field. When the server does a redirect to the login page, all form fields are lost because a redirect cannot contain POST data.

If you want your users to be able to take longer than 20 minutes to fill in the form, you can consider having some javascript on the page containing the form, which makes an ajax call to the server every x minutes. With sliding expiration, this will reset the session expiration time everytime the ajax call is fired, and thus it will *never* log your user out as long as they are viewing the page containing the form.

Comment: I understand there is also such as thing as cross-page posting. I thought this could have been a nice default mechanism for the viewstate to be persisted from the original page, through the login page and back to the original page again. But regrettably no!

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way, it's what I was looking for. I'm not keen on the idea of effectively disabling timeout of authentication though. I need to give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically save the contents of each control to Session as soon as it's filled in by attaching an AJAX-style `WebMethod` to the onChange event.

Using this method, the Session wouldn't time out so long as the user was diligently filling in at least one control every 20 minutes.

Comment: I don't understand this solution. How do I modify the page's viewstate using JavaScript, considering it is encoded? And how does storing stuff in ViewState help when the ViewState itself isn't being preserved? The AJAX part of it would prevent the timeout though, as Klaus described.

Comment: Page.ViewState actually isn't available from a WebMethod (far as I can tell) so I'll modify my answer.   The only remaining difference in my answer, then, is wiring up the AJAX to the onChange events.  Thanks.